Tensorflow model weights not loading correctly
i'm trying to load a tensorflow neural network in c++ for a chess engine. the model was trained in python and i'm converting the weights to a binary file, but the dimensions are wrong when loading in c++.
python model architecture:

input: 768 neurons (flattened 8x8x12 board state)
hidden layers: 1024 -> 512 -> 256 -> 128 -> 64
output: 1 neuron (tanh activation)

when loading in c++, i get dimension mismatches:
Input size: 768
Number of layers: 6
Processing layer 0
Input size: 1024 # should be 768
Output size: 768 # should be 1024

here's my python conversion code:
def convert_model_to_binary(model_path, output_path):
    # Load the TensorFlow model
    chess_nn = pickle.load(open(model_path, "rb"))
    model = chess_nn.model

    with open(output_path, "wb") as f:
        # write number of dense layers
        dense_layers = [
            layer
            for layer in model.layers
            if isinstance(layer, tf.keras.layers.Dense)
        ]
        np.array([len(dense_layers)], dtype=np.int32).tofile(f)

        for layer in dense_layers:
            weights, biases = layer.get_weights()

            # convert to float32 for c++ compatibility
            weights = weights.astype(
                np.float32
            )  # no transpose needed (weights are already in the correct shape)
            biases = biases.astype(np.float32)

            # write input and output dimensions
            input_dim = weights.shape[0]  # number of rows (input dimension)
            output_dim = weights.shape[
                1
            ]  # number of columns (output dimension)

            np.array([input_dim, output_dim], dtype=np.int32).tofile(f)
            np.array([output_dim], dtype=np.int32).tofile(f)  # bias shape

            weights.tofile(f)
            biases.tofile(f)

and c++ loading code:
bool load_model(const std::string &filename)
{
    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);
    int32_t num_layers;
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char>(&num_layers), sizeof(int32_t));
    layers.resize(num_layers);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_layers; i++)
    {
        int32_t weight_shape[2];
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char>(weight_shape), 2 sizeof(int32_t));
        int32_t bias_shape[1];
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char>(bias_shape), sizeof(int32_t));
        layers[i].input_size = weight_shape[1];
        layers[i].output_size = weight_shape[0];
        layers[i].weights.resize(weight_shape[0] weight_shape[1]);
        layers[i].biases.resize(bias_shape[0]);
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char>(layers[i].weights.data()), layers[i].weights.size() sizeof(float));
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char>(layers[i].biases.data()), layers[i].biases.size() sizeof(float));
    }
    return true;
}

what i tried:

transposing weights in python before saving:

weights = weights.T.astype(np.float32)

still got dimension mismatches but in reverse order

swapping input/output dimensions in c++:

layers[i].input_size = weight_shape[0];
layers[i].output_size = weight_shape[1];

same errors but different dimensions

changing weight index calculation in c++:

size_t weight_idx = i * layer.input_size + j; // original
size_t weight_idx = j * layer.output_size + i; // tried this
size_t weight_idx = i + j layer.output_size; // and this

still getting wrong predictions
expected:

weights should load with correct dimensions (768->1024->512->256->128->64->1)
model should give similar predictions to python version
input board state should process through all layers correctly

actual results:

dimensions are reversed (1024->768, 512->1024, etc)
getting "input size mismatch" errors at each layer
final prediction always returns 0


What does "same errors but different dimensions" mean? Make a simple example with complete inputs and expected and received outputs, that should make things clearer.
